# JPA criteria: order by child field gives error

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I have 3 entities. **Customer**, **Process** and **Document**.

A Customer has many processes and a process has many documents.

I want to sort customers by document's `updateDate`.

My entities are like below;

Customer-

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<>();

    // getter, setter etc.

}
```

Process-

```
@Entity
public class Process {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String type;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "process", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();

    //getter, setter etc.

}
```

Document-

```
@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String note;

    private LocalDateTime updateDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Process process;

}
```

I have tried the following specification-

```
  public static Specification<Customer> orderByDocumentUploadDate() {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            ListJoin<Customer, Process> processJoin = root.join(Customer_.processes);
            ListJoin<Process, Document> documentJoin = processJoin.join(Process_.documents);

            query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(documentJoin.get(Document_.updateDate)));
            query.distinct(true);
            return null;
        };
    }
```

It gives following error-

> ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select
> list

Generated SQL-

```
    select distinct customer0_.id   as id1_0_,
                customer0_.name as name2_0_
from customer customer0_
         inner join
     process processes1_ on customer0_.id = processes1_.customer_id
         inner join
     document documents2_ on processes1_.id = documents2_.process_id
order by documents2_.update_date desc
limit ?
```

I have also tried by grouping, like below-

```
    public static Specification<Customer> orderByDocumentUploadDate() {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        ListJoin<Customer, Process> processJoin = root.join(Customer_.processes);
        ListJoin<Process, Document> documentJoin = processJoin.join(Process_.documents);

        query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(documentJoin.get(Document_.updateDate)));
        query.groupBy(root.get(Customer_.id));
        return null;
    };
}
```

Then it gave a different error-

> ERROR: column "documents2_.update_date" must appear in the GROUP BY
> clause or be used in an aggregate function

Generated SQL-

```
    select
    customer0_.id as id1_0_,
    customer0_.name as name2_0_ 
from
    customer customer0_ 
inner join
    process processes1_ 
        on customer0_.id=processes1_.customer_id 
inner join
    document documents2_ 
        on processes1_.id=documents2_.process_id 
group by
    customer0_.id 
order by
    documents2_.update_date desc limit ?
```

I could do it by the following sql; `max()` solved it in below sql-

```
    select  customer.* from customer
inner join process p on customer.id = p.customer_id
inner join document d on p.id = d.process_id
group by customer.id
order by max(d.update_date);
```

But I can't do the same, using the `criteria` API.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

This is a conceptual misunderstanding.

- First, you have to understand how does inner join works. And this portion is okay in this case: [join `process` table with `document` table based on `document.process_id = process.id`]
- Second, you need to sort customers based on the document's update date

Unfortunately, you used `group by` here. `GROUP BY` only returns column in which it is `grouped by`. In this case, it will return only `customer_id`.

You can use aggregate functions like `count()`, `sum()` etc. on grouped data.

When you tried to access `update_date`, it will throw below error:

```
ERROR: column "documents2_.update_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

---

Now, how can we get rid of this?

- So first we need to do `join` to get customer id. After getting customer id, we should group the data by the customer id and then use max() to get max_date of each group(if necessary then minimum)

```sql
SELECT 
   customer_id,
   max(date) AS max_date
FROM    
   document 
   JOIN process ON process.id = document.process_id
GROUP BY customer_id
```

It will return a temporary table, that looks something like below:

| customer_id | max_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-24 |
| 2 | 2021-03-15 |
| 3 | 2020-09-24 |
| 4 | 2020-03-15 |

Using the temporary table, you can now sort `customer_id` by date

```sql
SELECT
    customer_id,
    max_date
FROM    
    (SELECT 
        customer_id,
        max(date) AS max_date
    FROM    
        document 
        JOIN process ON process.id = document.process_id
    GROUP BY customer_id) AS pd
ORDER BY max_date DESC
```

Hope this helps.